# using UIColors vs using images as background in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Is it a good practice to use UIColors to set the background colors in an iOS app? I am using this

```
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 120.0/255.0, green: 140.0/255.0, blue: 160.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

to set background colors in my app. I have these colors set to be returned when called by certain methods in a different swift file to keep the code in my View Controller clean. I have around 15 different colors that I wish to use in my app. There's not much more in the app yet and I was surprised to see that it is taking up 86MB of storage when installed on the device. Makes me wonder why...

1. Is it because of the UIColors and if yes, is it better to use images than UIColors while setting backgrounds?
2. I am not even setting these colors to the background yet so merely declaring them is using all that storage? (if it is UIColor that is using all that storage)
3. Any idea what is happening 'behind the scene' when using UIColor to set the background color of a view?

Came across [this](http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=855) but it went right over my head.

Comment: how big is your code?Not in abs but in lines approximately for all your views, subviews etc.Also are you sure you have no images in you Assets.xcassets?(or image in previews Xcode)

Comment: code shouldn't be more than a couple hundred lines. Nothing in Assets.xcassets, not even app icon

Comment: what makes you think it is the color code that's taking the space? can you remove your color code and compare?

Comment: Commented all that and it's still at 86MB so maybe it's the FontAwesome pod that I am using but I have used that in the past and never had an app use that much of space on the device.

Comment: So maybe it was copying all those inages included in the pod project that I included into my project.. I wonder why it wouldn't do that in the other project in which ai used Font Awesome. Only difference I can see is this one is in swift and that was objective C